# onclickads on my website

Tags: html

Hello I am the owner of hdasstios.ee.tn and I can modify code.

In my index.html there is no redirect code to onclickads.com and
i didn't putted that in my website..

[This is my website](http://www.hdasstios.ee.tn/)
([Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prZ88.png))

How can i fix this? And this is not just on my PC, its on my laptop, tablet, phone and friends pc...

I use subdomain ee, so does effect anything? I also have cpanel, and FTP.

Please help me, thanks :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about website administration, but I guess it would be more or less off-topic at serverfault, too.

Comment: Sorry, but im new here..No need to be rude :/

Comment: I did not intend to be rude, part of this is a text preset by the system. No hard feelings from my side!

Answer (score 0):

Remove everything in this div (including the div itself). Your site was hacked and a div containing a couple script imports were added - hijacking your button:

[image]

Comment: Amm..But where is that code? And how can i protect site from hacking?

Comment: It is buried in a random div at the bottom of your page.

Comment: Thank you! But how can I protect my website from this happening again?

Comment: Am..If open it in my text editor, i dont see anything..? http://i.imgur.com/Bvoxd6w.png

Comment: Hmm, try this. Open your dev console in Chrome, and click the Network tab an hit the reload button. Then check the network traffic. You will see the call for that import. Pay close attention to the filename and domain. Follow the local path to the culprit file.

Comment: GET /apu.php?zoneid=511821 HTTP/1.1
Host: onclickads.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: sr,sr-RS;q=0.8,sr-CS;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.4,en;q=0.2
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Can this be fixed?

Comment: That's the marker of the StampLive browser hijack. Infects your browsing client and hijacks various links. Details and removal instructions here: http://soft2secure.com/knowledgebase/stamplive

I don't think your site is infected - I think your computer is.